# open certmgr from command line and save cert to c:directory

Tags: wcf, ssl, command, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'am trying to export certificates from my personal store to c:drive location using certmgr in script

Does someone know what the command is, or can send me to some website. Thanks alot..

```
CertMgr /s /r CurrentUser my /put cert1.cer /s /r C:\
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command saves a certificate with the common name `myCert` in the `my` system store to a file called `newCert.cer`. (`certmgr` command is `certmgr.exe` instead of `certmgr.msc`)

> certmgr /add /c /n myCert /s my newCert.cer

Please refer to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/certmgr-exe-certificate-manager-tool
Besides, we could refer to the below Powershell cmdlet, which can export a certificate to a file, the difference between these commands is whether the private key and some other extended properties are exported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps
Here is an example of exporting a certificate to a PFX file.

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\5F98EBBFE735CDDAE00E33E0FD69050EF9220254 | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\mypfx.pfx -Password $mypwd
```